# Reduce inter staff length in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

When I try to reduce the inter staff length, it seems it doesn't work. As a result two page score is generated, so it is needed reduce the score to one page.
The basic code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \input musixjt
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \begin{center}
    \Bigtype Practicando Lectura\\[1ex]
    \end{center}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \interstaff{3}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \setinterstaff{1}{3}%Distancia entre sistemas del pentagrama
    \nobarnumbers
    \setclef1\treble
    \generalmeter{\meterC}
    \parindent0mm
    \nostartrule
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    \scale{1.0}
    \startbarno=1
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás - 1ra línea
    \notes\zcharnote{g}{\hspace*{-2.05cm} \huge{\textcircled{\A\bfseries\large 55}}}\qsk\ibu0c{2}\qb0{c}\tqh0d\ibu0e{2}\qb0{e}\tqh0f\ibu0g{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0h\ibl0i{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0j\ibu0i{-1}\qb0{i}\tqh0h\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{g}\tqh0f\qu e\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibu0e{2}\qb0{e}\tqh0f\ibu0g{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0h\ibl0j{1}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ibl0k{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0l\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0l\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0j\ibu0i{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0h\qu g\en
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 2da línea
    \notes\ibl0n{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0m\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibu0g{-1}\qb0{h}\tqh0g\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0g\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibl0k{1}\qb0{j}\tqb0k\ql{l}\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0g\ibu0e{-2}\qb0{f}\tqh0e\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibu0d{2}\qb0{d}\tqh0e\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0g\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ql{j}\en\setdoublebar
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 3ra línea
    \notes\ibu0e{2}\qb0{e}\tqh0g\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0h\ibu0g{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0i\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0j\en\bar
    %2do compás
    \notes\ibl0i{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\ibl0j{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0l\ibl0k{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0m\ql l\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibu0g{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0i\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\ibl0k{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0l\en\bar
    %\4to compás
    \notes\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0m\ibl0m{2}\qb0{l}\tqb0n\ibl0n{2}\qb0{m}\tqb0o\ql n\en
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 4ta línea
    \notes\ibl0n{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0l\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0k\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0i\en\bar
    %2do compás
    \notes\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0h\ibl0i{-2}\qb0{i}\tqb0g\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0f\qu g\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0i\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0h\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0g\en\bar
    %\4to compás
    \notes\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0f\ibu0f{-2}\qb0{g}\tqh0e\ibu0e{-2}\qb0{f}\tqh0d\qu{c}\en\setdoublebar
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 5ta línea
    \notes\ibl0i{2}\qb0{g}\tqb0l\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0j\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0m\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\en\bar
    %2do compás
    \notes\ibl0m{2}\qb0{l}\tqb0n\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0l\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0o\ibl0n{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0m\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibu0h{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0j\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibu0h{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0j\en\bar
    %\4to compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibu0f{-2}\qb0{g}\tqh0e\qu{c}\qp\en
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 6ta línea
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %2do compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0j\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0f\qu{c}\qp\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0k\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0k\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\en\bar
    %\4to compás
    \notes\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0k\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0g\ql{j}\qp\en\setdoublebar
    \alaligne%\generalmeter{\meterC}\changecontext
    %1er compás - 7ma línea
    \notes\zchar0{\hspace*{-0.46cm} \meterC}\qsk\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0g\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ql j\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0g\ibu0f{-2}\qb0{f}\tqh0e\qu f\en
    \alaligne%\generalmeter{\meterC}\changecontext
    %1er compás - 8va línea
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibu0i{-2}\qb0{j}\tqh0h\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0h\ibu0g{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0i\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0j\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\qu g\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0g\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibu0i{-2}\qb0{j}\tqh0h\ibu0i{-2}\qb0{j}\tqh0h\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0g\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0g\ibu0f{-1}\qb0{f}\tqh0e\qu f\en\setdoublebar
    \alaligne%\generalmeter{\meterC}\changecontext
    %1er compás - 9na línea
    \notes\ibu0f{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0g\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibl0k{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0k\ibl0m{2}\qb0{l}\tqb0m\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibl0n{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0m\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\qu h\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibu0f{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0h\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0l\ibl0n{2}\qb0{m}\tqb0n\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibl0o{-2}\qb0{o}\tqb0n\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0l\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0j\ql i\en
    \alaligne%\generalmeter{\meterC}\changecontext
    %1er compás - 10ma línea
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0i\ibl0k{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0k\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0j\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0l\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibl0k{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0k\ibl0m{2}\qb0{l}\tqb0m\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0l\ibl0n{2}\qb0{m}\tqb0o\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0n{-2}\qb0{n}\tqb0m\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\ibl0m{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0l\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0k\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\ibu0g{-1}\qb0{h}\tqh0g\qu f\en\setdoublebar
    \alaligne
    %1er compás - 11va línea
    \notes\ibu0g{2}\qb0{f}\tqh0h\ibu0h{2}\qb0{g}\tqh0i\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\en\bar
    %2do compás
    \notes\ibl0k{2}\qb0{j}\tqb0l\ibl0l{2}\qb0{k}\tqb0m\ibl0m{2}\qb0{l}\tqb0n\ql m\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0k\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{l}\tqb0j\ibl0k{-2}\qb0{k}\tqb0i\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0h\en\bar
    %\4to compás
    \notes\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0g\ibu0g{-2}\qb0{h}\tqh0f\ibu0f{-2}\qb0{g}\tqh0e\qu f\en
    \alaligne%\generalmeter{\meterC}\changecontext
    %1er compás - 12va línea
    \notes\ibu0f{2}\qb0{c}\tqh0h\ibu0f{-1}\qb0{g}\tqh0f\ibu0h{2}\qb0{e}\tqh0i\ibu0g{-1}\qb0{h}\tqh0g\en\bar
    %2do compás:
    \notes\ibu0h{2}\qb0{h}\tqh0j\ibu0h{-2}\qb0{i}\tqh0h\ibl0j{2}\qb0{i}\tqb0k\ibl0j{-2}\qb0{j}\tqb0i\en\bar
    %3er compás
    \notes\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\ibl0n{2}\qb0{m}\tqb0o\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %4to compás
    \notes\ibl0l{-2}\qb0{m}\tqb0j\ibl0i{2}\qb0{h}\tqb0j\qu f\qp\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \endpiece
\end{music}


\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output should be (note that is needed one page for the score):
[image: desired]

Comment: Can't reproduce your screenshots: my lines only hold 3 bars. Not sure, if you handle fonts correctly in your code. Also, can your paper-geometry be a problem?

Comment: @MS-SPO: did you musixflx? Without that you indeed get one line with three bars and a second line with one bar.

Comment: You do a lot lately with musixtex. May I ask, what you try to create on the long term? I'm asking, because I have best experience with mixing lilypond and LaTeX manually. Maybe it might also a good choice for you.

Comment: Interesting... Is it there a basic example code you can share that combines both Musixtex with Lilypond ?

Comment: This starts to become a conversation? If so, there's a chat room for it. Moving your converstaion there allows to keep the comments here focused on the question. // See here for details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: @C.Peters, no I didn't. I just pasted and compiled the code posted. Which is strange, as it seems to give a different result in the TO's environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\interstaff`, but  `\stafftopmarg=1\Interligne`.
Normally you can define the vertical length with

```
\special{papersize=8in,21in}% Paper format
\vsize=20in%
```

And you could adapt the margins of your standard document class, but for your purpose for now, the first adaptation is enough, even though smaller margins and a larger distance between the lines would be preferable.

Comment: Also, we can use: \stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg0.8\Interligne\interstaff{4}\relax